# Dominant user defined cast operator

Tags: c++

Say I have two classes: `A` and `B`. I define how to cast `A` to `B` and `B` to `A`. I also define `operator<`, `operator>` and `operator==` for both of them, so I can compare an `A` to an `A` or a `B` to another `B`. Then I make an instance of class `A` , e.g. `a` and one of class `B`, `b`. I compare them:

```
if(a>b){...}
```

Which of them will get converted to match the other? Is there a way to influence this except explicitly casting?

EDIT: I made an example of my question, hopefully this will help explain myself.
Say i want to store integers. I can store them in `A` or in `B`. In `A`, i only sotore positive values. In `B`, only negative. The full code is below. If `a` gets converted to `B`, `a>b` is true. If `b` gets converted to `A`, it is false. Try it out. For me, if I don't cast elsewise, `a>b` is false. What I am asking is, can a conversion be made dominant so that in these situations, i can be sure what happens?

A.h

```
#ifndef _A
#define _A

class B;

class A{
    private:
        int val;
    public:
        A(int val);
        operator B()const;
        bool operator==(const A& a)const;
        bool operator>(const A& a)const;
        bool operator<(const A& a)const;
};

#endif
```

B.h

```
#ifndef _B
#define _B

class A;

class B{
    private:
        int val;
    public:
        B(int val);
        operator A()const;
        bool operator==(const B& b)const;
        bool operator>(const B& b)const;
        bool operator<(const B& b)const;
};

#endif
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

A::A(int val){
    this->val=val>=0?val:-val;
}
A::operator B()const{
    return B(-val);
}
bool A::operator==(const A& a)const{
    return val==a.val?true:false;
}
bool A::operator>(const A& a)const{
    return val>a.val?true:false;
}
bool A::operator<(const A& a)const{
    return val<a.val?true:false;
}
```

B.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

B::B(int val){
    this->val=val>0?-val:val;
}
B::operator A()const{
    return A(-val);
}
bool B::operator==(const B& b)const{
    return val==b.val?true:false;
}
bool B::operator>(const B& b)const{
    return val>b.val?true:false;
}
bool B::operator<(const B& b)const{
    return val<b.val?true:false;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

int main(){
    A a(5);
    B b(-7);
    if(a>b) cout << "a>b is true"   << endl;
    else    cout << "a>b is false"  << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: For me, it's always the right operand of `>` that gets cast (in main). Also, if I declare the comparison operators as friend functions, the code wont compile, with the error `ambiguous overload for 'operator>' in 'b > a'`, which I kind of expected.

Answer (score 0):

`operator>` will not cast anything.  It will merely compare the two operands with a defined overload.  If there is no such overload, your code will not compile.

It would look like this:

```
bool operator>(const A& lhs, const B& rhs)
{
   return lhs.foo > rhs.bar; //
}
```

If you want a conversion between `A` and `B` you would take `B` in `A` constructor so you can do this:

```
A::A(const B& b) {} //do stuff to convert B to A

A a = someb;
```

which is equal to `A a(someb);`